# Doctrine : does `execute` method execute only its specific request or it flushs all statements in the queue

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I can't find in the Doctrine documentation if the `execute` method executes only its specific request or if it flushs all statements in the queue like `flush` does.

Consider code like this:

```
...
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($cache);
...
$this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('DELETE ReportBundle:Report r WHERE r.id = :id')
    ->setParameter('id', 1)
    ->execute();
```

As there is no `flush` method at this time, does `$cache` entity will be created when `execute` will be called or not?

Doctrine documentation linnk would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cache` entity will not create, because of the`execute` is the method of `Query`, it works only with `Query` that you created. When the `EntityManager` works with the `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: I did some tests and you are rigth : the entity is not peristed.